# MySQL returning fewer rows in Result Set than Limit

Tags: mysql

We have a query that runs like this:

```
select distinct(id) 
from TABLE 
where date_id >= :startDate 
and date_id <= :endDate 
limit :offset,5000
```

The issue is - sometimes this query returns 5000 rows, sometimes 4999 from what I can tell. The trick is also, yesterday, I could get a particular offset (125000) to return 4999 every time I ran it, but today, it's now gone back to 5000.

Any idea why this could be happening? I've read that MySQL's limit is just that, a limit, return **AT MOST** n numbers of rows, but what I want to understand is the actual mechanics behind when MySQL makes that decision.

Thanks

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function.

Comment: Are you sure there ARE (or were) AT LEAST 5000 records to be returned? Also date comparison should be against DATE fields and not DATETIME fields as the time might screw things up

Comment: Yeah, I noticed this at offset 125000, which returned 4999 rows. Offset 130000 also returned 4999 rows, and the count on this query returned 325000 rows

Comment: Just in case `distinct is not a function` isn't clear: the parentheses in your query used after the word distinct are just ignored. Instead the word distinct belongs to previous word making: `select distinct` which applies to ALL columns included in the select list.

Comment: Something similar happened to us when the DB was overloaded (millions of entries, with no indexes matching the respective query; and `limit 10` was randomly returning different counts like 2, 3, 6, ...)

Answer (score 1):

As we cannot reproduce your results (sometimes 4999 -v- mostly 5000) all I could offer is that one row less met the criteria when 4999 was returned. Note that **the second parameter is a maximum**, so if the there are no more rows to present it will stop at the last row and this can mean less rows than the second parameter are returned.

MySQL documentation says:

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants...
>
> ...
>
> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the
>   first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of
>   rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):
>
> ```
>  SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
> ```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html